# Sorting data based on column date

Tags: vb.net, csv

I have a csv file similar to this:

```
Test Case   Lower   Upper   Actual  Date
Measure      2        8       3     4/14/2016 9:18
Measure      2        8       3     4/14/2016 11:16
Measure      2        8       5     4/12/2016 19:19
Measure      2        8       7     4/22/2016 10:36
Measure      2        8       6     4/22/2016 12:39
```

My goal is to plot a line chart from the data available from the above csv, the actual csv file contains a few thousands of line. My chart will have the Lower,Upper and Actual column in the x-axis and the date in the y-axis(Based on the week number).

I wanted to plot the chart based on the date (From oldest to latest). If you notice the "Date" column, the values are messed up and not in ascending order based on the date.

My plan is to create another csv file (Sorted.csv) and place the data in ascending order and perform my chart plotting from there. I stuck as I couldn't find a way to sort all the data based on the date. If I am able to get the Sorted.csv created, I can continue with my goal. This is my sample function:

```
Private Function sortCSV()
        For Each rawRows As String In File.ReadLines("C:\sampleVBPrograms\SimplePlot\SomeFile.csv")
            'I wanted to sort each line and place into a new csv "Sorted.csv" here
            'Just stuck in the way to sort, writing into Sorted.csv, I can do
        Next
    End Function
```

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Hari

Comment: So the only thing I got from all of this is you want to, `sort all the data based on the date`? What is your attempt? One option, create a class with properties to put that data in, then you could sort it any way you want to...

Comment: @Codexer, edited my question with a function that I plan to use. I can't post whatever I had done here because my code is huge

Comment: @Hari Don't post all your code, just post the one that you tried to sort the data you have. This way it seems you didn't try anything, which isn't how SO actually works. It's better to show your trial and errors to help fixing, not writing from scratch.

Comment: Read the data into something like a List(Of T), sort it, write it back out if you think you have to.  Something like CSVHelper will make reading and writing the CSV file very simple.  Besure to use a `DateTime` var for the data data so it acts like a date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of methods to sort lists of various type.
Here I consider an implementation of `.OrderBy()` and `.Sort()`.

A Class used as container for the data read from the source file.

```
Public Class LineObject
  Public Property TestCase As String
  Public Property Lower As Single
  Public Property Upper As Single
  Public Property Actual As Single
  Public Property ItemDate As DateTime
End Class
```

Create a `List(Of LineObject)` and fill it with your data:
**EDIT:** Set the separator to a comma.

```
Dim myLines As New List(Of LineObject)()
Dim firstLine As String()
Dim lineParts As String()

Using reader = New StreamReader("C:\sampleVBPrograms\SimplePlot\SomeFile.csv")
   'firstLine keeps the Header of the following data
   firstLine = reader.ReadLine().Split(","c)
   'Read the file and split using Comma as delimiter
   While (reader.Peek() >= 0)
      lineParts = reader.ReadLine().Split(","c)

      'The Date Field is parsed using the InvariatCulture Comparer
      'See if this setting suits your needs
      myLines.Add(New LineObject With {
          .TestCase = lineParts(0),
          .Lower = CType(lineParts(1), Single),
          .Upper = CType(lineParts(2), Single),
          .Actual = CType(lineParts(3), Single),
          .ItemDate = Date.Parse(lineParts(4), CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)})
   End While
End Using

'Order the list using a verbose .OrderBy()
Dim OrderedMyLines As IOrderedEnumerable(Of LineObject) =
  myLines.OrderBy(Function(t) t.ItemDate, Comparer(Of DateTime).Default)
```

Another method using `Sort()`.
I'm using a custom Comparer for this. Since Dates are compared, you might want to adjust it to your culture style.

```
Public Class LinesComparer
   Implements IComparer(Of LineObject)

   'Implements a Compare method for IComparer.
   'See that the date evaluation differs from the one used in .OrderBy()
   Public Function Compare(x As LineObject, y As LineObject) As Integer Implements IComparer(Of LineObject).Compare
      Return x.ItemDate.CompareTo(y.ItemDate)
   End Function
End Class

'Sort the list using the custom Comparer
Dim comparer As New LinesComparer()
myLines.Sort(0, myLines.Count, comparer)
```

**EDIT:**
Write to a file any of the ordered lists:

```
Using writer = New StreamWriter("C:\sampleVBPrograms\SimplePlot\sorted.csv")
  writer.WriteLine(String.Join(Chr(44), firstLine, 0, firstLine.Length)
  For Each line As LineObject In OrderedMyLines
     writer.WriteLine(
         $"{line.TestCase},{line.Lower},{line.Upper}" &
         $"{line.Actual},{line.ItemDate}"
     )
  Next
End Using
```

Comment: Thaks for your explanation. I am trying to implement .OrderBy() method you suggested. I was able to the variable OrderedMyLines. But, I couldn't write it into a csv file. I had tried with a foreach loop to write into a csv file but to no avail. Are there any way to loop through the variable and write into csv that you can suggest? This is to verify that I am getting the sorted value

Comment: @Hari What separator are you using?

Comment: I am using comma

Comment: @Hari  I've edited a bit the code because I think it's better to explicitly implement the Using block.

Comment: @Hari Glad it helped. Maybe try both sorting methods to see which performs better. I think the Sort() method is faster, considering the whole process. But, it depends. It can also be easily transformed in an async method, if you are interested.

Comment: I will definitely try in future when I am doing some clean up on the code. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Because your date is stored in "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" format you have to give a comparing method to the sorting method, where you split your date value and reorder their sequence so that you get something that is more like: "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm" (biggest element first)

So all in all: Reformat your dates and be happy :)